# click button sends second click data to db instead of the first one php/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have 1 button that changes its atributtes everytime I click on it, it have 3 options, 0, 1 and 2.
If the button is in 0 and I click it one time it will change to value 1 in its html structure, thats working fine, but it will send to DB the value 0, if the button is in 0 but I click it twice, it html structure changes to 2, but it sends value 1 to DB.

HTML:

```
<td class="dt-body-center">
                  <?php if($deposito["subido"] == 0): ?>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnSubido" idSubido="<?=$deposito["id"]?>" estadoSubido="0">Down</button>
                    <?php elseif($deposito["subido"] == 1):?>
                      <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs btnSubido" idSubido="<?=$deposito["id"]?>" estadoSubido="1">Up</button>
                    <?php elseif($deposito["subido"] == 2):?>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btnSubido" idSubido="<?=$deposito["id"]?>" estadoSubido="2">Ofc</button>
                  <?php endif;?>
              </td>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".tablas").on("click", ".btnSubido", function(){
        var idSubido = $(this).attr("idSubido");
    var estadoSubido = $(this).attr("estadoSubido");
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax/subido.ajax.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                estadoSubido: estadoSubido,
                idSubido: idSubido
            }
        });

        if(estadoSubido == 0){

        $(this).removeClass('btn-danger');
        $(this).addClass('btn-success');
        $(this).html('Up');
        $(this).attr('estadoSubido',1);

    }else if(estadoSubido == 1){

        $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
        $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
        $(this).html('Ofc');
        $(this).attr('estadoSubido',2);

    }else if(estadoSubido == 2){
            $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
            $(this).removeClass('btn-primary');
            $(this).html('Down');
            $(this).attr('estadoSubido',0);
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
require_once '../includes/conexion.php';

$tabla = "depositos";

$item1 = "subido";
$valor1 = $_POST["estadoSubido"];

$item2 = "id";
$valor2 = $_POST["idSubido"];

$sql=" UPDATE $tabla SET $item1 = $valor1 WHERE $item2 = $valor2 ";

$query = false;

if($db->query($sql)===TRUE){      
    $query = true;
}
```

Comment: have you checked all if else working ?

Comment: yeap, it's working now, @faelks answer did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like maybe you want to move your ajax request to the bottom of the click handlers, in order to have the html element attribute (`estadoSubido`) change **before** you execute the request.

```
$(".tablas").on("click", ".btnSubido", function () {
  var idSubido = $(this).attr("idSubido");
  var estadoSubido = $(this).attr("estadoSubido");

  // {if else block}

  // Get the new value, which your click handler changes it to.
  estadoSubido = $(this).attr("estadoSubido"); 
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/subido.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      estadoSubido: estadoSubido,
      idSubido: idSubido,
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Missed the 

// Get the new value, which your click handler changes it to.
  estadoSubido = $(this).attr("estadoSubido"); 

Thanks, that worked!